# How can i find this transformation

Tags: complex-analysis, quasiconformal-maps

i need to find a transformation $w= az+b$ the takes the triangle $1,i,0$ to the triangle $0,2,1+i$.

I tried to use the fact the this transformation must take vertices to vertices but i get to a inconsistent system.

Comment: A map $z \mapsto az + b$, with $a \neq 0$ is conformal. That tells you which side of the first triangle must be mapped to the hypotenuse of the second.

Answer (score 2):

$w = (1 + i)(1 - z)$ will do it.

Comment: Hello, but how did u determine The coeficiente a,b? How is The relations between The vértices of The second triangle?